# Google search and urls with keywords

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to get the previous page's url and keywords (a user finds this site with these words) to find my site before visiting to it and post them in my sql table in php or javascript?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the search term and keywords _before_ then visit your site? Have you tried using Google Analytics? They, more or less, do what you ask, much better than what we most likely could do (since it's implemented all over the internet).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the previous link using PHP as well as JS.
To get the previous URL in PHP you can do it using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`
In JS you can use `document.referrer`.

And then you can filter keywords from referrer URL.

Comment: Just note that `HTTP_REFERER` is highly untrustworthy. Not only can it be manipulated, but it won't exist for some of your users since some routers/proxies/firewalls removes that header for privacy reasons.

Comment: Best way is use Google Analytics to track this kind of things or any others in the market

Comment: @huzaifa-umair Can I post them in my sql table if I use Google Analytics? And how?

Comment: @Akmaljon_Usmonov - Why do you need them in your DB? Can't you just let Google handle the analytics?

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson I need to add these data in my db. I need it really!

Comment: @Huzaifa Umair  I have been searching it for 5 hours but no exact answer was given. That's why Im here and need help(

Comment: I wanna ask you something else. Is it possible to get API from google analytics?

Answer (score 0):

If you will use Google Analytics nd wanna store data into mysql table. Then my answer is yes you can store by using 
 [Google Analytics core reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference)  and you can use their query explorer to see what data you can pull from it.

Also here is all their [libraries and sample code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries) that you can use as a tutorial. I hope it is helpful